# JavaScript Tree with nodes containing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I need to create a tree.

Every node has two 2-dimensional arrays, "statusTable" and "moveTable".

Every child must inherit it's parent's statusTable (a copy of it).

Every node should have 10 children.

Tree creation should stop when it reaches "maxDepth".

When I use the code below I realise that all nodes point to the same statusTable.

Any help please?

```
function NODE(p, statTable, movTable, depth)
{
    this.par = p;
    this.statusTable = statTable.slice();
    this.moveTable = movTable.slice();
    this.depth = depth;
}


function createChildren(parentNode)
{
    var childNode, m;

    if (parentNode.depth == maxDepth) return;


    for (m = 0; m < 10; m++) {

        moveTable = [];
        mainTable = parentNode.statusTable.slice();

        childNode = new NODE(parentNode, mainTable, moveTable, parentNode.depth + 1);

        createChildren(childNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all nodes point to the same statusTable? Each statusTable should be different array instance with the same references to children.

Comment: @Naor If i make a change in the statusTable of a child, then the statusTable of it's parent is affected too.
That's why i believe they all reference the same array.

Comment: `if(parentNode.depth = maxDepth)` should be `if(parentNode.depth === maxDepth)`.

Comment: @Vivin Yes, that's a copy error, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slice creates a copy of the array, but you only used it on the outer array. The inner arrays are the same.

You have

```
var inner = [1];

var outer = [inner];
var copy = outer.slice();

copy === outer // false
copy[0] === outer[0] // true
copy[0][0] = 3; // problem
console.log(outer[0][0]) // 3, expecting 1
```

What you need is a deep copy instead of slice:

```
function deepCopy(arr) {
  var copy = arr.slice();
  for (var i=0; i<copy.length; i++) {
    if (copy[i] instanceof Array) {
      copy[i] = deepCopy(copy[i]);
    }
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! You're the man!! I've spent the last 3 days trying to deal with this. I'd never think of that. Thank you very much.

Comment: After it's finished, do I have to free the memory used by the tree manually, or it is done automatically? If manually, is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Any structure you don't have a reference to (have no way of accessing) will be garbage collected automatically.